# How do I disable Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one

I do not use Ubuntu One but that Ubuntu One ribbon keeps appearing when I open some folders. As I don't use Ubuntu One and don't intend to use it in near future, is there a way that Ubuntu One support completely goes away from my laptop? Something like `apt-get remove u1-support` so I no longer see that ribbon nor the preferences menu entry?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can uninstall the packages, yes. Ubuntu One involves two bits running on your computer: the Ubuntu One file sync client or `syncdaemon`, and desktopcouch backed by a CouchDB that replicates with the Ubuntu One CouchDB. If yo want to completely remove both, a quick way of doing that would be

```
sudo apt-get --purge remove .*ubuntuone.* .*couch.*
```

If all you want to do is disable the file synchronization daemon, however, you can simply disable the service in `ubuntuone-preferences`, from the Services tab:

[image: Ubuntu One Preferences' Service tab]

Comment: Is CouchDB being used for any thing else too? bcoz in my system when i run "dpkg -l|grep couch" i see packages like "evolution-couchdb" and running the above apt-get command will remove these too. Are these packages related to ubuntu one too?

Comment: @binW, `evolution-couchdb` is the package that makes your desktopcouch address database available to evolution. Right now, unless you've installed or built something yourself, Ubuntu One will be the only reason you have it installed.

Comment: Ubuntu One is used to synchronize CouchDB databases, including Firefox bookmarks, Evolution contacts and Tomboy notes. But it also includes databases from other applications that use DesktopCouch.

Answer (score 3):

You should go to Software center or Synaptic and uninstall the ubuntuone-client pakage if you want to remove all of ubuntu one(including gnome integration).

if you want to remove just the ubuntuone gnome integration(right click menus,applets etc)  then just remove ubuntuone-client-gnome .

Answer (score 0):

You should try :

```
rm –rf ~/.local/share/ubuntuone
rm –rf ~/.cache/ubuntuone
rm –rf ~/.config/ubuntuone
rm –rf ~/Ubuntu\ One
sudo apt-get purge ubuntuone-client* python-ubuntuone-storage*
```

It should remove dependencies and the ribbon (hopefully) with the config files been removed.

Answer (score 0):

the ubuntu one help site has this helpful page if you want to get rid of it ...
[How do I completely remove and reinstall Ubuntu One?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/how-do-i-completely-remove-and-reinstall-ubuntu-one/)
Just don't reinstall I guess