# How to disable Ubuntu One Signin Screen

Tags: ubuntu-one

Whenever I reboot and login, a window titled "Back Up" and "Connect to Ubuntu One" appears, containing a button named "Sign into Ubuntu One". I don't like Ubuntu One, nor any other proprietary cloud backup service, and I will never use Ubuntu One.

How do I disable it and/or permanently remove it?

I tried all the solutions suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23183/how-do-i-disable-ubuntu-one), but I still get the window.

I've uninstalled all "Ubuntuone" packages I can find, but this window still appears. Oddly enough, even if I click the button, nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing seems not to rise from Ubuntu One but from your Back-up service, probably Dèja-Dup. You should at least disable it from your start-up applications. Check [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69810/how-do-i-add-remove-the-hidden-startup-applications) how to remove hidden applications at login.

Comment: This was it, thanks. The complete lack of the name "Deja-Dup" coupled with the plastering of "Ubuntu One" everywhere was understandably confusing.